# Theming with SCSS & nuxt

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm trying to allow my users to have different themes to choose from however I can't seem to get it working. I've tried multiple different ways, one way is having two different files and i import them based on if the theme is light/dark however once it's imported it stays on the page. Another is within SCSS like this:

```css
$enable-rounded: true;

[theme="dark"] {
  $blue: #232c3b;
  $body-bg: #262626;
  $body-color: white;
}
[theme="light"]  {
  $body-bg: #ffffff;
  $body-color: #000000;
}

@import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
@import 'bootstrap-vue/src/index.scss';
```

then in my layouts/default.vue:

```js
import(`~/assets/scss/main.scss`)
export default {
data() {
  return {
    darkMode: false,
  }
},
mounted() {
  let bodyElement = document.body;
  bodyElement.classList.add("app-background");
  let htmlElement = document.documentElement;
  let theme = localStorage.getItem("theme");
  if (theme === 'dark') {
      bodyElement.setAttribute('theme', 'dark')
      this.darkMode = true
  } else {
      bodyElement.setAttribute('theme', 'light');
      this.darkMode = false
  }
},
watch: {
    darkMode: function () {
      let htmlElement = document.documentElement;
      if (this.darkMode) {
          localStorage.setItem("theme", 'dark');
          htmlElement.setAttribute('theme', 'dark');
      } else {
          localStorage.setItem("theme", 'light');
          htmlElement.setAttribute('theme', 'light');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

however nothing happens when I do it this way. I've been trying to figure it out for days and can't seem to get it. It makes me want to just use CSS and avoid SCSS even though I really want to use scss

Answer (score 0):

I think you are importing your scss file in a wrong way. Please try importing it like below out of the script part:

```
<style lang="scss">
   @import '~/assets/scss/main.scss';
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this for your project, you can switch into themes or custom on your own

https://color-mode.nuxtjs.org/